# Display custom object data to ListBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListBox in WPF application as :

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,37,0,16" Name="lbEmpList" Width="194" SelectionChanged="lbEmpList_SelectionChanged" FontSize="12" SelectionMode="Single">

</ListBox>
```

I have three buttons: Add, Remove and Update that will add, remove and update items to the list box. I am adding Items to the ListBox my custom class object names *objEmployee*.
This custom class contains few properties: Id, Name, Address. 

But, when I add the object to ListBox, then it will display items as

```
<Namespace Name>.<Custom Object name>
```

How can I bind any of the object property to this ListBox at Design or run time to acheive my functionality?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Couple of options:

The first, easiest option is to set the ListBox's [DisplayMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) property to a property of your custom object. So if your Employee class has a LastName property you could do this:

```
<ListBox DisplayMemberPath="LastName" ... />
```

If you want more control over the data that's displayed for each item (including custom layout etc) then you'll want to define a [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) for each item in your ListBox. The easiest way to do this is by simply setting the ListBox's [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) property:

```
<ListBox ...>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Have a read through the links I've provided and check out some of the example code on MSDN.